# Pandas unusual groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need an unusual group by in a huge dataframe. I simplified the df for the purpose of clarity. Is it possible to group by years including the last visible
december date of previous year as part of the next year, but also including this date as part of the actual year?

```
data = {'date': ['2017-03-31', '2017-04-03', '2017-12-27', '2017-12-28',
                 '2017-12-29', '2018-01-02', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-02',
                 '2019-01-03', '2019-12-31', '2020-12-30', '2020-12-31',
                 '2021-01-20', '2021-12-30', '2021-12-31', '2022-05-30',
                 '2022-05-31'] 
       }
df =pd.DataFrame(data)


Desired groupbys:
date          g1    g2    g3     g4    g5      g6
2017-03-31  2017                    
2017-04-03  2017                    
2017-12-27  2017                    
2017-12-28  2017                    
2017-12-29  2017  2018              
2018-01-02        2018              
2018-12-31        2018  2019            
2019-01-02              2019            
2019-01-03              2019            
2019-12-31              2019  2020      
2020-12-30                    2020      
2020-12-31                    2020  2021    
2021-01-20                          2021    
2021-12-30                          2021    
2021-12-31                          2021    2022
2022-05-30                                  2022
2022-05-31                                  2022
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a `pivot` after duplicating the last date of each year:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

out = (pd
 .concat([df.assign(year=d.dt.year),
          df[df.groupby(d.dt.year, as_index=False).cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0)
            & d.dt.month.eq(12)
            ].assign(year=d.dt.year+1)])
 .assign(col=lambda d: 'g'+d.groupby('year').ngroup().add(1).astype(str))
 .pivot_table(index='date', columns='col', values='year')
 .convert_dtypes()
)
```

output:

```
col           g1    g2    g3    g4    g5    g6    g7
date                                                
2017-03-31  2017  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2017-04-03  2017  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2017-12-27  2017  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2017-12-28  2017  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2017-12-29  2017  2018  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2018-01-02  <NA>  2018  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2018-12-31  <NA>  2018  2019  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2019-01-02  <NA>  <NA>  2019  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2019-01-03  <NA>  <NA>  2019  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2019-12-31  <NA>  <NA>  2019  2020  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2020-12-30  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  2020  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2020-12-31  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  2020  2021  <NA>  <NA>
2021-01-20  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  2021  <NA>  <NA>
2021-12-30  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  2021  <NA>  <NA>
2021-12-31  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  2021  2022  <NA>
2022-05-30  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  2022  <NA>
2022-05-31  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  2022  2023
```

##### groupby only

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

out = (pd
 .concat([df.assign(year=d.dt.year),
          df[df.groupby(d.dt.year, as_index=False).cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0)]
            .assign(year=d.dt.year+1)])
      .groupby('year')
      # perform your aggregation here

)
```

Comment: Sorry i was unclear. I really dont want the output. I was thinking a way to have one groupby that could attend this rule, so that i can apply some functions in the groups

Comment: Complementing. I just need a rule to group by year, but the last date of year ( yyyy -12 -??) should be in two groups at the same time. 2017-12-29 should sum the column value in 2017 and 2018.

Comment: @Fcoatis you can't directly have a groupby that reuses one item, but you can do as I did in the first part, duplicate the last december date and then you can groupby month period (let me give an example)

Comment: Have you had a chance to test?

Comment: Actually i used your idea and came up with: 

    `df2 = df[df.groupby(d.dt.year, 
    as_index=False).cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0)].assign(year=d.dt.year+1)
    datas = df2.date.to_list()
    datas.insert(0, '2017-01-01')

    for a, b in zip(datas, datas[1:]):
        str = a + ' : ' + b
        print(str)`